# Flutter: Image not loading

Tags: flutter

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions provided has worked for me. I am new in flutter and I am facing a problem with adding an image to my application. Most probably it's a problem with my pubspec.yaml file as many sources in the internet show, but I have tried making sure there are no wrong indentations or errors. I even have prettier extension installed which auto formats the pubspec file when I save but all attempts have proved useless.
What could possibly be the problem, please advice. Thanks for any support

Below is my code for my login page file and my pubspec.yaml file:
**
Login.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: h * 0.3,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/loginimg.png")),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: firstapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: try this command in terminal

 'flutter clean'  and 
 'flutter pub get'

then kill or uninstall the app and again run the app 
and also please check the "loginimg.png" image name is the same in the folder assets/images/

Comment: Have you tried deinstalling and reinstalling the app? This could be necessary so that the assets folder is correctly loaded

Comment: Yes, i've been trying for three days now, the assets are in the root directory and they are all fine.

Comment: i've tried recreating the app, performed flutter clean and flutter pub, ran the app again and suprisingly, it did not show me an image loading error but still displayed nothing. I should let you know though that if I try adding an image from the internet, it get's displayed.

Comment: can you try `Image.asset("assets/images/loginimg.png")` and see if it works !!

Comment: you wrap your image with a container that only has a width: 2, are you sure the width is 2?

Comment: Actually, I was following a tutorial, I did't realise that he had changed his width values without recording. So the problem was not about the image loading, it was the width value

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Move the line back like this:

```
  assets:
  - assets/images/
```

Also if your assets folder is in lib directory, you need to add lib:

```
  assets:
  - lib/assets/images/
```

Also make sure the spelling are exactly the same as the directory.

If all of the above still didn't work, try the following in flutter terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

If still not working, check your flutter doctor in terminal:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this line correct?

```dart
width: 2,
```

Probably it should be changed to:

```dart
width: w,
```

The full code:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: LoginPage()
        );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: w,
            height: h * 0.3,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("images/default.png")),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]